# Android Automotive app crashes when clicking in Input text field after typing few letters in SigninTemplate

Tags: android, android-automotive, automotive

I am facing an issue in my Android Automotive application. I am using the SigninTemplate, and when I click in the input text field after typing few letters, the app crashes. It happens if I click anywhere on the text-field. This only happens if I have already typed some letters in the input text field. But if the input text field is empty and I click it, the only thing that happens is that it is focused and the keyboard is opening.

**The error message:**

```
Connection lost
android.os.DeadObjectException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:571)
at androidx.car.app.activity.renderer.IRendererCallback$Stub$Proxy.onCreateInputConnection(IRendererCallback.java:297)
at androidx.car.app.activity.BaseCarAppActivity$2.lambda$registerRendererCallback$1(BaseCarAppActivity.java:178)
at androidx.car.app.activity.BaseCarAppActivity$2$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
at androidx.car.app.activity.ServiceDispatcher.fetch(ServiceDispatcher.java:116)
at androidx.car.app.activity.BaseCarAppActivity$2.lambda$registerRendererCallback$2$androidx-car-app-activity-BaseCarAppActivity$2(BaseCarAppActivity.java:176)
at androidx.car.app.activity.BaseCarAppActivity$2$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.onCreateInputConnection(Unknown Source:4)
at androidx.car.app.activity.renderer.surface.TemplateSurfaceView.onCreateInputConnection(TemplateSurfaceView.java:160)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1928)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.restartInput(InputMethodManager.java:1858)
at androidx.car.app.activity.renderer.surface.TemplateSurfaceView.onStartInput(TemplateSurfaceView.java:210)
at androidx.car.app.activity.BaseCarAppActivity$2.lambda$onStartInput$7$androidx-car-app-activity-BaseCarAppActivity$2(BaseCarAppActivity.java:213)
at androidx.car.app.activity.BaseCarAppActivity$2$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.run(Unknown Source:2)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Remote exception (host render service)
android.os.DeadObjectException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:571)
at androidx.car.app.activity.renderer.surface.ISurfaceListener$Stub$Proxy.onSurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceListener.java:181)
at androidx.car.app.activity.renderer.surface.SurfaceHolderListener.lambda$notifySurfaceDestroyed$2$androidx-car-app-activity-renderer-surface-SurfaceHolderListener(SurfaceHolderListener.java:103)
at androidx.car.app.activity.renderer.surface.SurfaceHolderListener$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
at androidx.car.app.activity.ServiceDispatcher.lambda$dispatchNoFail$1(ServiceDispatcher.java:90)
at androidx.car.app.activity.ServiceDispatcher$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.invoke(Unknown Source:2)
at androidx.car.app.activity.ServiceDispatcher.fetchNoFail(ServiceDispatcher.java:153)
at androidx.car.app.activity.ServiceDispatcher.dispatchNoFail(ServiceDispatcher.java:89)
at androidx.car.app.activity.renderer.surface.SurfaceHolderListener.notifySurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolderListener.java:102)
at androidx.car.app.activity.renderer.surface.SurfaceHolderListener.surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolderListener.java:78)
at android.view.SurfaceView.notifySurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceView.java:1981)
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface(SurfaceView.java:1157)
at android.view.SurfaceView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.java:345)
at androidx.car.app.activity.BaseCarAppActivity.lambda$onStateChanged$3$androidx-car-app-activity-BaseCarAppActivity(BaseCarAppActivity.java:399)
at androidx.car.app.activity.BaseCarAppActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.run(Unknown Source:4)
at androidx.car.app.utils.ThreadUtils.runOnMain(ThreadUtils.java:39)
at androidx.car.app.activity.BaseCarAppActivity.onStateChanged(BaseCarAppActivity.java:385)
at androidx.car.app.activity.BaseCarAppActivity.$r8$lambda$dw3rK9QfgsUWuk2bAICsaK01RZs(Unknown Source:0)
at androidx.car.app.activity.BaseCarAppActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.onChanged(Unknown Source:4)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:151)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:309)
at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
at androidx.car.app.activity.CarAppViewModel.lambda$onError$0$androidx-car-app-activity-CarAppViewModel(CarAppViewModel.java:185)
at androidx.car.app.activity.CarAppViewModel$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:4)
at androidx.car.app.utils.ThreadUtils.runOnMain(ThreadUtils.java:39)
at androidx.car.app.activity.CarAppViewModel.onError(CarAppViewModel.java:177)
at androidx.car.app.activity.ServiceDispatcher.fetch(ServiceDispatcher.java:119)
at androidx.car.app.activity.BaseCarAppActivity$2.lambda$registerRendererCallback$2$androidx-car-app-activity-BaseCarAppActivity$2(BaseCarAppActivity.java:176)
at androidx.car.app.activity.BaseCarAppActivity$2$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.onCreateInputConnection(Unknown Source:4)
at androidx.car.app.activity.renderer.surface.TemplateSurfaceView.onCreateInputConnection(TemplateSurfaceView.java:160)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1928)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.restartInput(InputMethodManager.java:1858)
at androidx.car.app.activity.renderer.surface.TemplateSurfaceView.onStartInput(TemplateSurfaceView.java:210)
at androidx.car.app.activity.BaseCarAppActivity$2.lambda$onStartInput$7$androidx-car-app-activity-BaseCarAppActivity$2(BaseCarAppActivity.java:213)
at androidx.car.app.activity.BaseCarAppActivity$2$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.run(Unknown Source:2)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

**Code in onGetTemplate() function:**

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public Template onGetTemplate() {
            InputCallback listener = new InputCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onInputSubmitted(@NonNull String text) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onInputTextChanged(@NonNull String text) {
                }
            };

            InputSignInMethod.Builder inputSignInMethod = new InputSignInMethod
                    .Builder(listener)
                    .setHint("Enter Details");


            return new SignInTemplate.Builder(inputSignInMethod.build())
                    .addAction(new Action.Builder().
                            setOnClickListener(ParkedOnlyOnClickListener.create(()->{})).setTitle("Log In").build())
                    .setTitle("Sign In")
                    .build();
    }
```

I have kept the code very basic.

I tried to debug and google the same issue, but unable to find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my implementation in kotlin, check if it help:

```
val usernameInput = InputSignInMethod.Builder(callback)
        .setHint("Username")
        .setInputType(InputSignInMethod.INPUT_TYPE_DEFAULT)
        .build()

    val passwordInput = InputSignInMethod.Builder(callback)
        .setHint("Password")
        .setInputType(InputSignInMethod.INPUT_TYPE_PASSWORD)
        .build()

    return SignInTemplate.Builder(passwordInput)
        .setTitle("Sign in with username and password")
        .setInstructions("Enter your password")
        .build()
```